# Unable to Fetch Form Values in Code Behind to Perform Insert Into DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have an aspx data entry page which accepts user input for certain fields and inserts into the database.

There are like 2 sections (Referred as S1 and S2 in the rest of the question)

S1 has 3 text input controls and 2 radio buttons. Similarly, S2 also has 3 text input controls and 2 radio buttons.

**What is expected?**

Upon clicking submit, the code behind must insert S1 fields' values into S1 table and similarly, S2 fields' values into S2, successfully.

**What is going wrong?**

Only S1 table values are populated in the DB and S2 table is empty. No records get entered in S2.

With the help of the debugger I discovered that all the input field values entered by user after the radio buttons of S1 are not getting accepted at all. They are blank.

The SQL queries are all correct. I even tried swapping S1 section with S2 on the aspx page. When I did that, S2 values got entered into DB but not S1. Again, the input field values of S1 present after the radio buttons of S2 were not being read.

Someone told me it is some sort of postback issue.

**ASPX Code of Section 1 (S1) [S2 code is similar]**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" CssClass="form-control lw-sharp-corners" placeholder="Enter Release Title"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtReleaseDescription" runat="server" CssClass="form-control lw-sharp-corners" placeholder="Enter Release Description"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtReleaseUrl" runat="server" CssClass="form-control lw-sharp-corners" placeholder="Enter Release Url"></asp:TextBox>
<div class="form-group" id="ActivateRelease">
<label for="rdoActivateRelease" id="lblActivateRelease">Activate Release?</label>
<div class="radio">
    <label for="rdoActivateReleaseYes" id="lblActivateReleaseYes">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoActivateReleaseYes" GroupName="rdoActivateRelease" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        Yes
    </label>
    <label for="rdoActivateReleaseNo" id="lblActivateReleaseNo">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoActivateReleaseNo" GroupName="rdoActivateRelease" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        No
    </label>
</div>
```

**CS Page Code of Section-1 (S1) [S2 code is similar]**

```
protected void btnMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ReleaseTitle = "";

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertRelease", con);
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtTitle.Text;
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@ReleaseDescription", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtReleaseDescription.Text;
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@ReleaseUrl", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtReleaseUrl.Text;
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@DeviceType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2;

    int ActivateState1;
    if (rdoActivateReleaseYes.Checked)
    {
        ActivateState1 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ActivateState1 = 0;
    }
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@IsActive", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ActivateState1;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader drRelease = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    while (drRelease.Read())
    {
        ReleaseTitle = drRelease.GetValue(0).ToString();
    }
    con.Close();
```

Please tell me how to fix this. Let me know if you need any code.

Comment: Can you show us your aspx and cs code ?

Comment: @TusharGupta  I have added the correct code. Let me know if you need more details

Comment: Can you add complete aspx code? Are these two sections falls under same FORM tag?

Comment: Where is your form.? Are you using any MasterPage? Is there a single Button or multiple?

Comment: after postback the radio button value remains checked ? i mean did u check your radio button is still shows checked after s2 code exicution

Comment: put your S2 code too

Comment: @Amit The complete aspx code is very long. The code given here is the crux. Yes both sections fall under same FORM  tag

Comment: @TusharGupta Yes I have a master page. I am using single button

Comment: @ArunPrasanth Firstly, i don't see any distinct postback happening. Second, there are no 2 separate executions. It is one single button click execution. After i check the radio buttons of S1 and move on to fill S2 field values, everything is correct and normal. Only when I click submit the field values of S2 are not read

Comment: Atleast put both sections. Although they are similar as you saying but worth looking. What is btnMap_Click and where it is called?

Comment: @ArunPrasanth Give me few minutes, i will give more code for reference.

Comment: ok put s2 section please

Comment: @Amit Give me few minutes, i will give more code for reference.
btnMap_Click is the submit click event upon which I will insert the data into DB

Comment: Then btnMAP should call two methods such as S1Insert(), S2Insert()

Comment: @Amit You were right asking about the number of FORM tags. I just noticed I had included another form tag by mistake which caused the issue. Put across your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add complete aspx code? Are these two sections falls under same FORM tag?

Comment: Yes, you pointed out right. I had accidentally introduced additional form tag! Thanks!